# "...the study carried out" or "...the carried out study"

Tags: difference, word-order

I could not find a plausible explanation since there is a lot of examples of both variants.

What should I write:

> *In the case of the carried out study,...*
> or
> *In the case of the study carried out,...*

May I use both versions interchangeably?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The "rules" aren't hard-and-fast. It seems to me that your example is further on the side of "non-idiomatic" than, say, [*the **conducted** study*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+conducted+study%22). At least that one gets plenty of hits in Google Books, although it's nothing like as "acceptable" as, say, *the **completed** study*. It might help to consider the fact that ***carried out*** is a "multi-word verb form". As a general principle, "compound" verbs only usually work ***after*** the noun (so it's ***living** children*, but *children **living in poverty***).

Comment: My PhD supervisor would always change "carried out" to "performed" if that helps at all.

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine: That doesn't explain why [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+performed+study%2Cthe+carried+out+study&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20performed%20study%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20carried%20out%20study%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20performed%20study%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20carried%20out%20study%3B%2Cc0) shows that ***the performed study*** is much more common than ***the carried out study***, whereas...

Comment: [...this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+study+performed%2Cthe+study+carried+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20study%20performed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20study%20carried%20out%3B%2Cc0) shows ***the study carried out*** as being more common that ***the study performed***.

Comment: I probably should have appended a verb such as ***was*** to all my NGram search strings, to restrict results to contexts where the noun phrases *the X study* and *the study X* are definitely functioning as the ***subject of a verb***. I think that makes a difference to acceptable contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That might be because "the carried-out study" would look wrong to more people so they'd be more likely to try to find an alternative? My supervisor obviously didn't think the other way around sounded academic enough either, so would replace it, but it wouldn't bother other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your examples are correct from a strict grammar point of view. It should be:

> In the case of the carried-out study...

(a phrasal adjective modifying the noun "study" requires a hyphen)

> In the case of the study which was carried out...

(you need some sort of link between the noun "study" and the past participle "carried")

---

But continuing to the usage of the phrase, I agree with FumbleFingers that it sounds awkward. As is *always* the case, more context would be helpful when trying to answer your question. But I might write it like this:

> In the case of the study **as it was carried out**...

(if you're highlighting the differences between the study as it was originally planned and as it actually worked)

or:

> In the case of the **completed** study...

(if you're distinguishing between a study that was conducted all the way through and another study that is not yet complete)

or:

> In the case of the **conducted** study...

(if you're distinguishing between a study that was actually run and another study that never left the planning stages)

Comment: I think OP knows that ***carried out*** isn't idiomatic (syntactically valid?) when placed before the relevant noun. I'm not sure if you're agreeing with me (and Google Books! :) that ***conducted*** is "less unidiomatic" than ***carried out*** (but it's still a bit "odd" compared to, say, ***completed***, which works perfectly well before OR after the noun). But the point is, OP wants to know ***why*** some verbs work before the noun, but others don't (or at least, *don't work very well*).